# Del-bar commuting with averaging operator

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions, complex-manifolds

Let $G$ be a compact  group (possibly finite) acting holomorphically on a complex manifold  $(M, J)$. Then  we have an averaging map $$\rho: \Omega^{p,q}(M) \rightarrow \Omega^{p,q}(M)$$ $$\omega \mapsto \int_{G} g^*\omega ~~ dg$$

where $\int_{G}  dg =1$.

Is it true that $\rho \circ \overline{\partial} (\omega) =  \overline{\partial} \circ \rho(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega^{p,q}(M)$?